# How to update PSReadline properly in PowerShell 7.2.5?

Tags: powershell

I am not sure whether this question has been asked before, but I was unable to find the solution to this problem. I have installed PowerShell 7.2.5 (not Windows PowerShell) and this version is shipped with PSReadline.

I used: `Get-Module -ListAvailable` to make sure that I saw PSReadLine 2.1.0. in C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\Modules. However, this is a bit unfortunate, since it is not installed with `Install-Module`, I cannot remove it using `Remove-Module` or `Uninstall-Module`.

Thus, I tried `Install-Module -Name PSReadLine`. However, it says:

> WARNING: Version '2.1.0' of module 'PSReadLine' is already installed
> at 'C:\program files\powershell\7\Modules\PSReadLine'. To install
> version '2.2.6', run Install-Module and add the -Force parameter, this
> command will install version '2.2.6' side-by-side with version
> '2.1.0'.

However, I do not want to install it side by side, I just want 2.2.6, rather than both. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

All instances of Powershell need to be closed. (Don't forget vscode, windows terminal, etc. which might run one.)

You may then remove the folder PSReadline from Program Files using Windows Explorer and install current version running following as admin (Win + R, enter command below, then ctrl+shift+enter to run it as admin.)

`pwsh -noprofile -command "Install-Module PSReadLine -Force -SkipPublisherCheck -scope allusers"`

PSReadline will then be installed in $env:ProgramFiles\PowerShell\Modules

Comment: Thanks, I added your answer to the github issue as well: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGetv2/issues/644